# PIL: PNG being read with 4 channels but it is black and white

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, channel

I am opening an image using PIL but its shape is being read as (400, 256, 4) whereas it should be (400, 256, 1). Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(file_name)
img = np.array(img)
print(img.shape) # (400, 256, 4)
```

Does it have to do with how I encoded the image when I made it, or is there a way to read it in as 1 band?

For reference on the image, I encoded it using matplotlib's https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Comment: Seems valid. 3 channels for R,G,B, plus one channel for transparency. It probably depends on how you used matplotlib's savefig on what kind of png is stored (i'm assuming grayscale png's are possible without extra alpha-channel; i also thinkg RGB+alpha is a good default for mpl). I would trust PIL here, but you can always try some other tool to check that image. You can ignore the alpha-channel and do a grayscale-conversion, but this is a lossy operation (and we assume matplotlib does not need the alpha-channel; not sure if that's true).

Comment: the whole point of black and white is to use 1 channel to represent brightness values, so I don't want more data than I need. I don't see any parameter in savefig that allows for modifying how the png is stored so i figure it must be how it is being read in but alas I cannot find anything on how to ask PIL to read in data with a specified number of channels.

Comment: You misunderstand. You did not show the code used to save and therefore it's highly probable that matplotlib used 3-4 channels (which would be a good idea by default). Either you check your code or you check the output with some other tool. But you seem to do nothing but complain about PIL. It's easy to convert channels to grayscale, but it would be wise to check the earlier steps.

Comment: yea i think i am misunderstanding you because i don't find any functionality that allows you to save a plot as a b&w png in matplotlib's documentation. The code I use is effectively two lines: `plt.plot(event_segm, 'k', linewidth=1)` where even_segm is just an array of y values and `plt.savefig(fig_name,
    bbox_inches = 'tight',
        pad_inches = 0)`. Is there anything here you see?

Comment: It will save a non-grayscale png and therefor PIL is right. I also can't follow your logic. You did not find any way to generate a grayscale-PNG, but complain about PIL reading it as non-grayscale. There are multiple other questions here on how to generate grayscale-png's within matplotlib.

Comment: well thanks for your great criticism. it helped me so much. for anyone else who wants a quick solution, just run the bash command 'convert -type Grayscale [images]'.